# WebApi proxy throughput

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, proxy, owin, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a web application with a bunch of backend micro-services, and a single gateway application handling concerns such as SSL offloading, authorization, routing, etc...

The gateway is a mix of self-hosted Owin and WebApi. The Owin pipeline handles almost all of the gateway logic before reaching WebApi, while the WebApi middleware is made of a proxy handler that uses HttpClient to forward calls to backend services.

On my own dev machine the gateway adds very little overhead to the communication: ~10ms

But when I call them on another test machine, the overhead increases significantly.
For example: 126K of data from the backend take 11ms to finish (results from Fiddler), but the same data through the gateway takes ~600ms to arrive.

My proxy handler simplified:

```
internal class ProxyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Some modification on the requestUri to forward it to the backend here...

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);

        return response;
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

- When I change the HttpCompletionOption to ResponseContentRead (basically buffering the whole response), the request time drops almost to the same levels as a local call.
- I dug pretty deeply into the code of WebApi.Owin and found HttpMessageHandlerAdapter to try changing the buffering behavior. Defining my own policy selector that always buffers also fixes the issue:

  ```
  private void UseGateway(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
  {
      HttpMessageHandlerOptions httpMessageHandlerOptions = new HttpMessageHandlerOptions
      {
          BufferPolicySelector = new MyBufferPolicySelector(),
          ExceptionHandler = new NullExceptionHandler(),
          ExceptionLogger = new NullExceptionLogger(),
          MessageHandler = new ProxyHandler()
      };

      appBuilder.Use<HttpMessageHandlerAdapter>(httpMessageHandlerOptions);
  }


  internal class MyBufferPolicySelector : IHostBufferPolicySelector
  {
      public bool UseBufferedInputStream(object hostContext)
      {
          return false;
      }

      public bool UseBufferedOutputStream(HttpResponseMessage response)
      {
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

This all points to some sub-optimal behavior on the message body stream translation between HttpClient, WebApi, and Owin but I'm at a loss at how to fix it without buffering the entire response.

- Final note: The test machine is a pretty weak VM on my LAN, but I doubt it's so weak it can't copy streams fast enough.

Does anyone know about this behavior?
What is the proper way to fix it?
Maybe it's some lab environment quirk that will be fixed in the real world?
Maybe I shouldn't use HttpClient and go to more basic implementations such as HttpWebRequest?

Comment: Maybe I have got things wrong, but it seems like you are trying to implement reverse proxy manually (on the web application level). Have you cinsidered a real reverse-proxy server usage (ARR, nginx, other web server implementations) instead of manually doing this work on application level? Maybe it could help you to avoid such low-level things like buffering and requests marshalling...

Comment: You are not wrong. I joined this project in the middle, so most of it is already done, and I didn't investigate alternatives so far. From what I understand, our gateway is rich enough that nginx or ARR aren't quite enough

Comment: I guess though that switching to IIS instead of self hosting can be an option if it will help